# openCV Mat N-dimensional reshape

Tags: c++, opencv, reshape

I have a cv::Mat mat returned from dnn::blobFromImage that is size 1x3x600x450. (img is BGR w/o an alpha channel)

```cpp
cv::Mat mat = dnn::blobFromImage(img);
cout << mat.size() << endl; // 1x3x600x450
```

What is the analog to numpy.reshape to reshape this to 3x600x450?

In python, if I assert that mat.shape[0] == 1, then with numpy.reshape I would do something like

```py
mat = mat.reshape((mat.shape[1], mat.shape[2], mat.shape[3]))
```

What is the equivalent in OpenCV?

Comment: Maybe just create a new `cv::Mat` header for the original `Mat`'s data, which drops the first dimension? Just keep the original `Mat` alive as long as that secondary is, and you'll be fine (without having to make copies). `1x3x600x450` and `3x600x450` will have the same in-memory layout, so this should work IMHO. | or maybe [this overload](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a13ccd8740a42616d650ae9495e43eb2d)?

Comment: Thanks Dan. Something like:  int sz[] = {mat.size[1], mat.size[2], mat.size[3]};
    Mat newmat(3, sz, mat.type(), mat.ptr<float>(0));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per Dan's response in the comments above, this is what I went with:

```
cv::Mat mat = dnn::blobFromImage(img);
cout << mat.size() << endl; // 1x3x600x450

int sz[] = {mat.size[1], mat.size[2], mat.size[3]}; 
Mat newmat(3, sz, mat.type(), mat.ptr<float>(0));
cout << newmat.size() << endl; // 3x600x450
```

Comment: I run similar code as yours with OpenCV 4.5.1, but `cout << mat.size() << endl` does not output the complete shape of `mat`. It only outputs `3x1`. CORRECT: you can get the complete shape by calling `mat.size` instead of `mat.size()`.